# 'Client' Excel Workbook unable to close 'Host' Add in using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 workbooks called Client.xls and Host.xlam

The objective is as follows

1. When the Client is opened it also opens the Host add in
2. The Host add in closes the Client workbook
3. When the Client workbook closes it also closes the Host add in

For some reason when I run this process the Host add in is left open?

Here is my code

Client.xls

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

MsgBox ("Open Host")
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\nggmgwr\Desktop\Host test\Host.xlam")

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    MsgBox ("Close Host")
    Workbooks("Host.xlam").Close

End Sub
```

Host.xlam

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    MsgBox ("Close Client")
    Workbooks("Client.xls").Close

End Sub
```

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the fundamental purpose of an add-in. Add-ins load with the host *application* (Excel), and remain loaded as long as that application is open. That's literally by design. If you need a standard macro-enabled workbook, use that, don't make an add-in.

Comment: I'm trying to keep all the code in the add in so it can control the client workbook without affecting the client workbook in any way but i need the client workbook to close the 'control' add in when it shuts

Comment: An Excel add-in closes when Excel is closed. If that's not how you mean it to work, then you probably don't want an add-in. Also you have workbooks A and B; if A opens B, then A must close B, and B can't know about A, otherwise you have circular dependencies. Again: the "client" has no business closing/unloading an add-in.

Comment: Interestingly it seems to work fine if I close the Client workbook manually i.e. if the request to close 'Client' comes from client it will happily close down the Host add in but doesn't succeed if the request to close client comes from the Host add in